# Angular 2 Reactive Forms Slowness

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have an Angular 2 application in which I am using reactive forms to validate a table of data cells (each row is a FormGroup with its own set of validations).

I've found that when there are multiple rows (10+) the speed at which the validations occur diminishes, sometimes freezing for many rows (50+).

I assume it's the browser memory usage that is slowing down and freezing the application - Is there anything I can do to reduce it?

Also, what would be the best tool to monitor the browser memory usage (aside from task manager)?

Thanks!

Comment: put angular in your tags instead of angularjs. This was you will reach right people with your question

Comment: You can do a lot of things. 1 - Change the Row/Grid `ChangeDetectorStrategy`, you can use `OnPush`. 2 - Use a VirtualRepeater in your Grid, so you only show 5/10 Rows and when you scroll it will change the data of these rows, that's the trick. 3 - Find code smells, maybe someone introduce a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - I've looked into `ChangeDetectorStrategy` and `VirtualRepeater`, but I'm not sure if they would work: `ChangeDetectorStrategy` with `OnPush` limits the changes recognized to when new inputs are set, which isn't what I'm looking for.
`VirtualRepeater` might work from a DOM rendering standpoint, but what's eating the memory is the backend Reactive Form Validation on each of 100s of rows.
If the client approves, I'll implement validation for each row only after the user clicks an Edit icon.